# Access Image via OpenCV in python (ROS Kinetic)

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, ros

I want to access my camera using OpenCV in ros kinetic,
this is my code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7
import rospy
from sensor_msgs.msg import Image
import cv2
from cv_bridge import CvBridge, CvBridgeError

rospy.init_node('opencv_example', anonymous=True)
bridge = CvBridge()

def show_image(img):
    cv2.imshow("Image Window", img)
    cv2.waitKey(3)


def image_callback(img_msg):
    try:
        cv_image = bridge.imgmsg_to_cv2(img_msg, "passthrough")
    except CvBridgeError, e:
        rospy.logerr("CvBridge Error: {0}".format(e))
    
    show_image(cv_image)
    
sub_image = rospy.Subscriber("/raspicam_node/image/compressed", Image, image_callback)
cv2.namedWindow("Image Window", 1)

while not rospy.is_shutdown():
      rospy.spin()
```

all I get after this code is a blank image window

before you ask the topic address, I can access the camera with this command   `rostrum image_view image_view image:=/raspicam_node/image/ _image_transport:=compressed`

currently, I am working with

- Ubuntu 16.04
- Ros Kinetic
- Open CV 3.3.1

Comment: I don't use ROS, but I guess there are a  few possibilities... either the image never arrives, or it does arrive and it is empty, or you aren't displaying it correctly. I would add some debug statements like `import numpy as np` and `print np.mean(cv_image)` and if it is printed the image has arrived, if it is zero the image is empty and if it is non-zero, there is a problem with displaying it.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I use ROS and you were basically there. ROS has a specific type for compressed images and the OP is using it. It's showing as nothing because they're trying to use it in OpenCV as a normal non-compressed image.

Answer (score 0):

You've answered your own question, the image is coming in compressed. Because of this your subscriber is also wrong there is a specific `sensor_msgs` type for [Compressed Images](https://docs.ros.org/en/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/CompressedImage.html).

Using `numpy` you can decode the image directly in your subscriber like so:

```
def image_callback(img_msg):
    np_arr = np.fromstring(img_msg.data, np.uint8)
    image_np = cv2.imdecode(np_arr, cv2.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR)
    
    show_image(cv_image)
```

As stated earlier, your subscriber also needs to look like

`sub_image = rospy.Subscriber("/raspicam_node/image/compressed", CompressedImage, image_callback)`

And you need to include `from sensor_msgs.msg import CompressedImage`

Edit:

Based on your comment you can also republish the compressed image as an uncompressed image to use with your original code using `image_transport`.

If you want to use `rosrun` in the terminal: `rosrun image_transport republish compressed in:=/raspicam_node/image/compressed raw out:=/raspicam_node/image/uncompressed`

Or if you're using a launch file:

```
<node name="republish" type="republish" pkg="image_transport" output="screen" args="compressed in:=/raspicam_node/image/compressed raw out:=/raspicam_node/image/uncompressed" />
```

Then you need to change your original code to

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7
import rospy
from sensor_msgs.msg import Image
import cv2
from cv_bridge import CvBridge, CvBridgeError

rospy.init_node('opencv_example', anonymous=True)
bridge = CvBridge()

def show_image(img):
    cv2.imshow("Image Window", img)
    cv2.waitKey(3)


def image_callback(img_msg):
    try:
        cv_image = bridge.imgmsg_to_cv2(img_msg, "passthrough")
    except CvBridgeError, e:
        rospy.logerr("CvBridge Error: {0}".format(e))
    
    show_image(cv_image)
    
sub_image = rospy.Subscriber("/raspicam_node/image/uncompressed", Image, image_callback)
cv2.namedWindow("Image Window", 1)

while not rospy.is_shutdown():
      rospy.spin()
```

Comment: ill try that thing and come with this message 
`'CompressedImage' object has no attribute 'encoding'`

in this [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/rospy_tutorials/Tutorials/WritingImagePublisherSubscriber)
they say, # We do not use cv_bridge it does not support CompressedImage in python, sorry for ask many question

Comment: @Anto I've edited my answer based on your comment. Please see if that works for you.

Comment: i use rosrun, `rosrun image_transport republish compressed in:=/raspicam_node/image/ _image_transport:=compressed raw out:=/raspicam_node/image/uncompressed` i have to go with this command, if i just type `/raspicam_node/image/compressed` there will always a warning to change the command.
Am i have to run the .py file in the other terminal? or the same terminal with previous rosrun command?. i change the code but the same thing happen, just a black window image

Comment: by the way, i use opencv 3.3.1-dev. Any idea this is a wrong version of opencv to run this code?